# Auth0 LinkedIn social connection access_denied error: "Cannot read property 'values' of null"

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using Auth0 for oauth social logins and up until this point I've had no issues connecting my Auth0 account to LinkedIn (having followed the guide here https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/linkedin months ago).

However, very recently I have been unable to successfully connect to LinkedIn. I have made no Auth0 management changes, and in fact no code changes in my application either. When I try to test the LinkedIn social connection, I get the "Bummer! Something failed" page, and the only error details provided are as such:

{
  "error": "access_denied",
  "error_description": "Cannot read property 'values' of null"
}

Given that I haven't actually made any changes to anything, and the fact that this error message is limited and doesn't seem to provide any good search results thus far online, I'm stumped.

I have also tried creating a new application on the LinkedIn developer platform and connecting that to my auth0 account, and after asking for permissions it results in this same error when testing the connection. I expect that only LinkedIn developers might have a clue as to what's going on, but any insight (even on how to get a more verbose error trail to follow) would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your rules. You may have made one to get the full size profile picture from LinkedIn like I did

https://manage.auth0.com/#/rules

Needed to update the code to null and empty string check the json

```
function (user, context, callback) {
    if (context.connection !== 'linkedin') {
        callback(null, user, context);
    }

    var request = require('request');
    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/picture-urls::(original)?format=json',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.identities[0].access_token
        }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(response.body);
            if (json !== null && json.values && json.values.length >= 1) {
                context.idToken.picture = json.values[0];
            }
        }
        callback(null, user, context);
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems the real problem is that LinkedIn has shutdown (or busted) the picture-urls endpoint.

Comment: This was exactly it, it had been a while since I had fiddled around with these settings and had completely forgotten about that possibility. Thanks a million, Jonathan!